# vim mapping normal keys like shift

Tags: vim, mapping

I want to map a key in Vim such that i would hold down a key, say a,
and then press some other key, say b. And then the holding down of the a would change what the pressing of b does.
Like the way we use shift, just with all the normal characters of the keyboard.

Is that possible?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to turn <kbd>A</kbd> into a normal modifier via `xmodmap` or the like, and the only modifiers vim supports are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Meta</kbd>, so not only do you lose normal functionality of the key, but you also add it to a set which contains one or more keys already.

Comment: Loosing normal functionality of the key is fine for i gain 24 other keys instead.

What's bad about adding to a set which contains one or more keys already?
Is it not possible?
And if it is possible, do you know where I can find how to do it?

Comment: As mentioned, the only modifiers you get are those 3, and Alt and Meta are treated the same. Anyways, you can use `xmodmap` to remap the keys in X (e.g. `xmodmap -e 'add Control = a'`). Don't know how for any other situations though.