# Vim: Map "hold down" keyboard combinations with keys other than ctrl and shift? (arbitrary modifiers)

Tags: vim

Can I create a mapping for say j(hold down)+l, that is separate from quickly typing j then l after each other?

This is somewhat a duplicate from [vim mapping normal keys like shift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124998/vim-mapping-normal-keys-like-shift), but I'm on Windows, so there's no xmodmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to do what I wanted with AutoHotkey.
I ripped out the spacebar from my keyboard and now I have lots of modifiers accessible with my thumb (instead of just space and AltGr). Here's my ahk script. It moves all letters one row up and maps v to space, b to backspace and n to enter. Note that I've only started working on this and that it's made for a swiss german layout.

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")
v::space
variable := ""
n:: variable .= ""


#If GetKeyState("n", "P") == 0 && WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")

b::Backspace
1::q
2::w
3::e
4::r
5::t
6::z
7::u
8::i
9::o
0::p
q::a
w::s
e::d
r::f
t::g
z::h
u::j
i::k
o::l
p::SC027
a::y
s::x
d::c
f::v
g::b
h::n
j::m
k::,
l::.
SC027::-
return 
#If

#If GetKeyState("n", "P") == 1 && WinActive("ahk_class Notepad")

b::Enter
k::;
1::+q
2::+w
3::+e
4::+r
5::+t
6::+z
7::+u
8::+i
9::+o
0::+p
q::+a
w::+s
e::+d
r::+f
t::+g
z::+h
u::+j
i::+k
o::+l
p::+SC027
a::+y
s::+x
d::+c
f::+v
g::+b
h::+n
j::+m
l:::
SC027::+-

return 
#If
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that in Vim with a simple mapping. You can press `j` then `l` but not the two together.

[But there's a plugin for that.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425)